# Expected an indented block error (django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models

This is my code

```
from __future__  import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.CharField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self): #

    return self.title


    def __str__(self):

    return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After function an indentation block is expected so

```
def __unicode__(self): #

return self.title
```

is wrong the correct way is

```
def __unicode__(self): #

    return self.title
```

Comment: Tried to do that still getting error as follows:

unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: do indentation properly use only spaces or only tabs for indentation

Answer (score 0):

Indent your definitions, as so:

```
def __unicode__(self): #

    return self.title


def __str__(self):

    return self.title
```